# React unsubscribe from RxJS subscription in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

A quick question regarding RxJS in useEffect hooks

I've noticed the React community uses this unsubscribe pattern with RxJS:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  const sub = interval(10).subscribe()
  return ()=>sub.unsubscribe()
})
```

I'm curious if this is due to convention/code clarity, or if I'm overlooking something. I would imagine the following would be simpler:

```
useEffect(()=> interval(10).subscribe().unsubscribe)
```

However, I could be overlooking something.

Edit: View selected answer. "This" is bound on method call, rather than on subscription instantiation. As a result, unsubscribe fails due to the "this" object not referring to the interval subscription, but rather the useEffect callback environment. Thanks to both contributors. Here is an example of the useEffect hook failing:  codesandbox.io/s/morning-bush-7b3m6h?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You may find [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/reactive-programming-with-react-and-rxjs-88d2789e408a) interesting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This here:

```ts
useEffect(()=>{
  const sub = interval(10).subscribe();
  return () => sub.unsubscribe();
});
```

could be re-written as:

```ts
useEffect(()=>{
  const sub = interval(10).subscribe();

  function unsub(){
    sub.unsubscribe();
  }

  return unsub;
});
```

The key thing to notice is that you're returning a function back to React. `unsub` isn't called right away, it's called later when the component unmounts.

In fact, you can return arbitrary code to be run later:

```ts
useEffect(() => {
  /****** 
   * Code that gets called when 
   * effect is run
   ******/ 
  return () => { // <- start of cleanup function 
    /****** 
     * Code that gets called to 
     * clean up the effect later
     ******/
  } // <- end of cleanup function
});
```

#### The problem

I'll rewrite your solution to make talking about the problem clearer. This is semantically equivalent, I've just introduced an intermediate variable.

```ts
useEffect(() => 
  const sub = interval(10).subscribe();
  return sub.unsubscribe;
);
```

The the question most clearly boils down to: What are the differences between these values? Under which circumstances (if any) will one fail while the other does not.

```ts
sub.unsubscribe
() => sub.unsubscribe()
```

If unsubscribe is a function (isn't bound to an instance of a class/object because it doesn't contain the this keyword), then the two are semantically equivalent.

The issue is that unsubscribe is not actually a function. It's a method on an subscription object. Because of this, the first value above is an unbound method where `this` is undefined. The moment the method attempts to use its context (`this`), JavaScript will throw an error.

To make sure that `unsubscribe` gets called as a method you could do this:

```ts
useEffect(() => {
  const sub = interval(10).subscribe();
  return sub.unsubscribe.bind(sub);
});
```

You have one less level of indirection this way, though it looks roughly the same.

Furthermore, I would recommend against using `bind` in most cases. Methods, functions, anonymous lambda functions, and attributes containing any of these three as values all behave differently on various edge cases.

As far as I know, `() => a.b()` may be needlessly wrapping a function, but will not fail. Plus JIT will optimize this fairly well 99.9% of cases.

Where `a.b.bind(a)` will fail on a previously bound method, but be optimized 100% of the time. I wouldn't use `bind` unless it's necessary (and it rarely is)

#### Update:

Just a quick aside: I use function here to denote a callable block of code which doesn't rely on a context (Doesn't have an object that it references using the `this` keyword) and a method to denote a callable block of code that DOES rely on some context.

If you prefer other terminology, that's fine. Swap out the words as you read them, I won't take offense, promise :)

Comment: Perfect!! "This" makes sense. I was overlooking that the "this" context is inherited from the calling environment unless explicitly bound. I'm used to working with subs in classes, and I incorrectly assumed that, once the sub function is called, "this" is bound to the resulting sub. However, as you pointed out, this was naive because "this" is implicitly bound on method call, rather than on object creation. Let me know if my explanation is wrong, but thank you so much! Also, RxJS unsubscribes do contain "this" and throw as a result: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-bush-7b3m6h?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ah, well done actually testing it! I'll update my answer to reflect that. In JavaScript, the way `this` works is one of the worts of the language. You're correct about how context works with `this`, though to confuse things sometimes objects will bind their prototypical functions at creation (some libraries do this with all their classes, for example).

Comment: Note that, practically speaking, there's nothing special about a "method" in JS. The term just describes a function that's part of an object (whether as an "own" property or via prototype). The important distinction is that "arrow" functions (from `(...) => ...` expressions) have different rules around things like `this`.

Also, I'm not sure I understand your opposition to `bind`. Maybe it "will fail on a previously bound method", but it will also fail on an arrow function. I don't see the downside.

Comment: @TheRubberDuck - AFAIK, the programming community at large (esp. OOP) refers to methods as functions that have access to the properties of an object/struct (Whether mutably or not). If you assign a function (say `(a,b) => a + b`) to the property of an object and call that a method - fine, we're no longer talking about the same thing. If we can get on the same page about semantics, I don't really care what you call it, I suppose. That f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶/̶m̶e̶t̶h̶o̶d̶ <insert a word here>'s context will not be the object it is attached to.

Comment: @MrkSef What I'm saying is that "methods" have no special `this` behavior. You actually **can** assign a function to the property of an object and get it to behave (in most ways) like a "method". Try `class A { x = 5; method() { return this.x; } }` and `const a = new A(); a.func = function() { return this.x; }`. Then both `a.method()` and `a.func()` return 5. Talking about methods at all is actually a distraction from the point; what matters is `this`.

Comment: @TheRubberDuck Eh. Tomato Toma-toe. Both `func` and `method` are methods. Or not. Whatever, JS is loosey goosey with it's terms. Even standard functions actual do have a context and can be thought of as methods on the Window Object or some-such.

Generally the distinction that matters isn't "Is it name-spaced with some object," but rather "Does it/can it use the values of some object"

Under THAT definition of method, talking about methods is exactly the right distinction. I'm not even sure what's being argued. The whole point is about how you access an object. So the this keyword of cours

Comment: I'm suggesting you remove talk of the word "method". It apparently doesn't have a standard meaning (for example, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Method) has a different definition than you) which may confuse people and your point can be made without it. What actually matters is what gets bound to `this` — which *may* copy the `a` in `a.func()` or it *may* ignore that and use a pre-bound value. That can happen to "methods" and non-"methods" (whatever that means, which isn't even clear), so "method" is just a distraction.

Answer (score 0):

## Beware of `this`

The short answer is that the `unsubscribe` function uses the `this` keyword and was designed to be called as a property of the subscription object (e.g., as `subscription.unsubscribe()) rather than "on its own" (e.g., as just` unsubscribe()`).

### What is `this`?

In JavaScript (in addition to the arguments passed to it and the closed-over values in scope) a function may use the `this` keyword to access a special contextual value. Originally, `this` was meant to be equal to the "receiver", or the object that the function was being called *from*. For example, if you set `a.f = f` and `b.f = f` with any function `f`, you can call `a.f()` and `this` will be equal to `a` or call `b.f()` and `this` will be equal to `b`. If you call `f()` by itself, `this` will be `undefined`.

### How does that matter?

In this case, `interval(10).subscribe()` returns a [Subscription](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subscription) object with an `unsubscribe` function that expects `this` to be that same subscription object. Particularly, [this line](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/47fa8d555754b18887baf15e22eb3dd91bf8bfea/src/internal/Subscription.ts#L54) of the current source code for `unsubscribe` checks `this.closed` to avoid re-closing subscriptions that have already been closed.

So, while you're *permitted* to pull `interval(10).subscribe().unsubscribe` away and call it without a receiver, you will get an error like "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'closed')".

### What can I do about it?

Unfortunately, it's not always clear when `this` is being used in a function that you didn't write. It's best to avoid isolating a function that came from an object (e.g., `const f = obj.func;`) unless you're sure it's `this`-free. But if a function is already "on its own", you don't usually have to worry about `this`.

However, there are the following workarounds:

1. **Wrap it in a new function** that always calls it with the expected receiver. This is what your example does: `() => sub.unsubscribe()`.
2. **Create a "bound" copy of the function.** Functions are objects too, and available to each function is the `bind` function that can be used to sort of hard-code the value of `this`. If you write `const unsub = sub.unsubscribe.bind(this);`, calling `unsub` will always call the `unsubscribe` function with `sub` as the value of `this`. This practically very similar to option 1 in that it creates a new function, but this is more streamlined to its purpose.
3. **Use an "arrow" function.** This isn't something consumers can do, but the `rxjs` authors could have written it this way: `unsubscribe = () => { ... }`. Then you could pull the function out and use it by itself with no errors. This is because "arrow" functions — functions created with the `() => ...` syntax — have special behavior: they always preserve `this` from wherever they were **created**. So when constructing a `new Subscription()`, it gets a dedicated `unsubscribe` function whose `this` value will always equal the constructed subscription object. But since the `unsubscribe` function is currently declared without the arrow syntax, it uses the typical `this`-equals-receiver behavior. Furthermore, since it's declared directly in the body of the `Subscription` class (rather than a value that gets assigned to the property) it's also part of the `Subscription` **prototype** and not part of the subscription object itself. Since it's shared across all instances, `this` can't refer to any specific instance but must look at the receiver.

Comment: To add to this:

3. Because prototypes **are** objects, you can't get away with an arrow function in many cases where you're using JS's OOP architecture. If they had written `unsubscribe` as an arrow function, the `this` keyword would point to the prototype and not to the instance.

Because RxJS's API is so functional, but their implementation leans fairly heavily on OOP, it's an interesting view into mixing styles of programming.

Comment: @MrkSef, I'm not sure that's quite correct. When you run: `class Test { static x = "static"; x = "instance"; unsubscribe = () => this.x }` and then `new Test().unsubscribe()`, the function  cal evaluates to `"instance"`.